# Tkinter box packing in loop is slow

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm running a slowish process of building a set of PDFs using LaTeX that's put together by my script.

The PDFs are built in a for loop. I wanted to show a status window that would add a line for each student that the loop goes through, so that you could see the progress. I have been doing this with `print`, but I wanted something that integrated well with the Tkinter interface that I have moved to.

I have this:

```
ReStatuswin = Toplevel(takefocus=True)
ReStatuswin.geometry('800x300')
ReStatuswin.title("Creating Reassessments...")
Rebox2 = MultiListbox(ReStatuswin, (("Student", 15), ("Standard", 25), ("Problems", 25) ))
Rebox2.pack(side = TOP)

OKR = Button(ReStatuswin, text='OK', command=lambda:ReStatuswin.destroy())
OKR.pack(side = BOTTOM)
```

and then the loop:

```
for row in todaylist:
```

and then, inside the loop, after the PDF has been made,

```
    Rebox2.insert(END, listy)
```

It inserts the row fine, but they all show up (along with the ReBox2 window itself) only after the entire loop is finished.

Any idea about what's causing the delay in display?

Thanks!

Comment: Try calling `Rebox2.w.update_idletasks()` after each row insertion. Some tasks in updating the display, such as resizing and redrawing widgets, are called idle tasks because they are usually deferred until the application has finished handling events. This forces that to happen before the application idles next normally. If you also call it right before the loop, it should make the ReBox2 window itself appear sooner.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't like .w.update; it's a multilistbox, rather than the standard listbox, so that may be the issue. I took out the .w and it ran, but didn't update faster.

Comment: That was a typo, sorry. Should have just been `Rebox2.update_idletasks()` -- i.e. without the `.w`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from what I can tell, there are two problems.  First, you are not updating the display with each new entry.  Second, you are not triggering the for loop with a button but instead having it run on startup (which means that the display won't be created until after the loop exits).  Unfortunately however, I can't really work with the code you gave because it is a snippet of a much larger thing.  However, I made a little script that should demonstrate how to do what you want:

```
from Tkinter import Button, END, Listbox, Tk
from time import sleep

root = Tk()

# My version of Tkinter doesn't have a MultiListbox
# So, I use its closest alternative, a regular Listbox
listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

def start():
    """This is where your loop would go"""

    for i in xrange(100):
        # The sleeping here represents a time consuming process
        # such as making a PDF
        sleep(2)

        listbox.insert(END, i)

        # You must update the listbox after each entry
        listbox.update()

# You must create a button to call a function that will start the loop
# Otherwise, the display won't appear until after the loop exits
Button(root, text="Start", command=start).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The whole thing really is triggered by a button; all of this is inside a function called by a button, and this MLB is generated on that button press. Long story short, though... `.update()` did it - it works just how I always wanted it to - thanks!